# How do I run code once a menu drop down has been clicked?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

In my android app I have an action bar with a button on it. When I press the button three drop down options appear on the screen. I want to be able to run code, such as run a function or go to another activity, when the user presses one of the buttons. My menu.xml is formatted as such and works fine. I just do not have a way to make the buttons do things when you press on them.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/dropMenu"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/threedots">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/pastDays"
            android:title="Past Days" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/aboutApp"
            android:title="About App" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/setNotifications"
            android:title="Set Notifications" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity, override the onOptionsItemSelected() method as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.pastDays){
        //Do something
    }
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.aboutApp){
        //Do something
    }
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.setNotifications){
        //Do something
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First use the overridden method, onCreateOptionsMenu(), to inflate your menu as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); // TODO: First param is your menu file

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

... and for functionality of when one of the menu items is clicked:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.pastDays:
            // TODO: Implement functionality here

            break;
        case R.id.aboutApp:
            // TODO: Implement functionality here

            break;
        case R.id.setNotifications:
            // TODO: Implement functionality here

            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```